# Apache permission issue

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, 15.04, lamp

Attempting to set up lamp on a new Ubuntu 15.04 install. I've probably set up lamp on Ubuntu 50 times but this one has me at my wit's end. Not only have I tried everything that I know to get this working, I have tried the accepted answers in no less than 6 similar questions here. I am simply getting no love at all. After all of the different machinizations this is where I stand right now.

I am getting 403 "You do not have permission..." on everything.

I have disabled the default site and set up a virtual server pointing to `~/web`. I have enabled `~/web`.

`/var/www` - Owner: Me. Group: www-data. And yes, I am a member of group www-data

`~/web` - Owner: Me. Group: Me. And yes, www-data is a member of group Me.

At various points I have had symlinks. Those were not successful. I have also had both `/var/www` and `~/web` owned by www-data, with myself as a member of that group.

The one thing that I am trying to avoid is 777 on `/var/www` for obvious reasons.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you are talking about `/var/www/`, if you're installing Apache in Vivid through `apt-get` or in any case you're not installing an older version on purpose by any mean you should have a version recent enough to have the new default root folder, which is `/var/www/html/`

Comment: And the ownership / settings of v/ar/www extend to /var/www/html/.

Comment: Ok, anyway there's no reason as far as I know to make `/var/www/` or `/var/www/html/` owned by you, and that might be source of the problem: just leave them as default (`drwxr-xr-x root root`) and, if you're the only user to administer the virtual hosts, recursively per each virtual host: 1. Own it 2. Set `www-data` as the group 3. Set permissions 750.

Comment: Just tried that.  Still getting the 403.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just leaving this here for others who may stumble across it and face similar issues.  After scouring the apache error log I traced the issue back to the apache2.conf file, where the virtual host was not properly set up (I had missed a bracket ).  Once I corrected that issue I was golden.  The lesson here is to actually check your logs rather than assuming that you are having the same problem as everyone else.